# Replacing a flanged copper pipe?

Tags: plumbing, repair, pipe

We were changing our bypass filter the other day, when the filter housing got stuck. Applied too much force without holding the surrounding plumbing, and bent the pipe that the filter is connected to. Woopsies.

The issue is, the pipe that's bent appears to be flanged at the bottom. See image below.

[image: flanged copper pipe?]

Is the removal process for this pipe going to be the same as any standard sweated joint?

If not, what do I do to remove this pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That copper tubing has been brazed with silfos or a similar type of solder. separating that joint will take a lot of heat. The standard soldering torch will not get hot enough to melt this product. You will need a "turbo torch" or an oxyacetylene torch to unsolder this fitting. If you are not versed in this type of equipment you better call a plumber. However if the copper is only kinked on the side shown you may not need to replace the kinked piece unless it is leaking. It probably is not restricted enough to reduce the water flow by very much.

Comment: How can you tell the difference between a pipe that's been soldered using a propane torch, and one that's been brazed as you say in your answer?

Comment: If the joint was soldered, you would see a silver ring at the point of connection. In your picture the copper looks as if it has been overheated which is normal when copper joints are brazed. The copper turns that ugly shade of red/purple. Depending on the the type of solder used, you could have broken the connection when the tubing twisted and kinked. You will never break a brazed joint. Also that is not a flange on the end of the copper tubing,  It is a reducer, unless someone " jerry rigged" the connection. You will be surprised what people do in a pinch.